# Android Center Oversized Bitmap On Canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have a bitmap that has greater dimensions than the canvas to which it will be drawn.  Can anyone suggest a method to center this bitmap on the canvas, i.e. the center point of the bitmap should overlap with the center point of the canvas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, Paint paint) with left and top new coordinates outside of the canvas, or using Canvas.drawBitmap (Bitmap bitmap, Rect src, RectF dst, Paint paint) with src null